# Store's listeners fired many times

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs

In my MVC 3 application, i want to refresh a partial View each time there is new available data. So to get these data from the server side, i'm using a componentLoader like below:

```
Panel lowerPanel = new Panel
        {
            Region = Region.South,

            Layout = "fit",
            ID = "WarningsPanel",
            AutoScroll = true,
            Loader = Html.X().ComponentLoader()
                .Url(Url.Action("_warningsView"))
                .Mode(LoadMode.Script)
                .MessageBusDirectEvents(
                new MessageBusDirectEvent()
                {
                    Name = "Warnings.Update",
                    Action = "_warningsView",
                    Buffer = 1000,
                    ExtraParams = { new { containerId = "WarningsPanel" } }

                }
               )
                .Params(new { containerId = "WarningsPanel" })
                .LoadMask(l => l.ShowMask = true)
        };
```

after getting new data from the server, i want to call some javascript functions. so i setted my partial view like below:

```
    @(Html.X().GridPanel()
                           .ID("WarningsGridPanel")
                            .EnableColumnResize(true)
                            .Store(Html.X().Store()
                                 .DataSource(Model)
                                            .Model(Html.X().Model()
                                                            .Fields(
                                                               Html.X().ModelField().Name("id"),
 ...
                                            )
                                           .Listeners(l =>
                                           {
                                                                       l.DataChanged.BroadcastOnBus = "Warnings.Register";
                                                l.DataChanged.Buffer = 5000;
                                           })
                                           .MessageBusListeners(mbl => mbl.Add(new MessageBusListener { Name = "Warnings.Register", Fn = "WarningsStore.Register"}))

                            )
                            .ColumnModel(//Html.X().RowNumbererColumn().Align(Alignment.Center).Width(Unit.Pixel(30)),
                                        Html.X().Column().Text("ID").DataIndex("id").Flex(1).Hideable(false),
...

                            )))
```

When refresh the partial view at the first time, i can see in the console that `WarningsStore.Register` JS function was called once but at the second time is called twice 
, third time is called 3 times ... 
This is how i defined the `WarningsStore.Register` JS function:

```
WarningsStore = WarningsStore || {};
WarningsStore.Register = function (message, id, eOpts) {...}
```

What can be the problem? is there many stores? am defining JS function in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call your function, you add a new MessageBusListener. You should add it only once.

Comment: You tagged your question ExtJs, but your code doesn't look at all like ExtJs. Sorry, I can't help you better.

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help
i just setted the MessageBusListeners properties Single to true

```
MessageBusListeners(mbl => mbl.Add(new MessageBusListener { Name = "Warnings.Register", Fn = "WarningsStore.Register", Single=true}))
```